# style different ul tags

Tags: html, css

I have in my page some ul and li tags there need to be styled different. I am not quite sure if that is what is called to make parent tags?

The picture shows that the circle with numbers from css 1 is repeated over where the css 2 should be used.

How can I do so the circles with numbers 1, 2 etc only are used with the html 1 and css 1?
So as my code is now, the

**HTML 1**

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 text-center feature-title">

                    <!-- Seminariet bulletpoints -->
                    <h2>HEADLINEU</h2>
                    <div>
                        <ul style="text-align:left">
                            <li>Text 1</li>
                            <li>Text 2</li>
                            <li>Text 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**HTML 2**

```
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <h2>PROGRAM FOR DAGEN</h2>
                            <ul class="cbp_tmtimeline">
                                <li>
                                    <time class="cbp_tmtime" datetime="2013-04-10 18:30"><span>4/10/13</span> <span>18:30</span></time>
                                    <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-phone"></div>
                                    <div class="cbp_tmlabel">
                                        <h2>Ricebean black-eyed pea</h2>
                                        <p>Winter purslane...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS 1**

```
ul {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style: none;
  position:relative;

    padding:0;

    display:inline-block;
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  line-height: 40px;



}
li:before {
  content: counter(section);
  counter-increment: section;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;


}
```

**CSS 2**

```
.cbp_tmtimeline > li {
    position: relative;
}

/* The date/time */
.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    padding-right: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span:first-child {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #bdd0db;
}
```

Comment: You need a class on your first list and style only that class - otherwise your "CSS 1" applies to all lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it specific to a class

```
.feature-title li:before {
 ...
}
```